# How do I repair these wires?

Tags: wire, cables

In the past I have occasionally repaired broken wires in various electronics around the home. However when trying to repair this cable for a Logitech USB headset, I discovered the wires are different from those I've come across in the past and also from those in the headphone repair videos I found on YouTube.

The headset has a mic and the wires appear to coiled around a thread and touching each other and not insulated with rubber.

How do I go about repairing these wires?

[image: headset cable]

Comment: It should be possible to strip the wires with aspirin (beware of nasty fumes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are enamelled.  Use a naked flame to burn the enamel off the very ends, give them a clean, then solder them as normal.  As @PlasmaHH says, the enamel stripped wires will now need insulating from each other.

Comment: You forgot to mention that afterwards they need some insulation that is gone now

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks.  I was just thinking about adding that, but I did think that would come under 'soldering then as normal'.  Best to say it though.